# Выдаёт ошибку связанную с 'distutils.cmd'

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm, python-3.8

[image: Вот сама ошибка]

**Версия Ubuntu: 22.04.1 LTS

Весрия Pycharm: 2022.3 Community Edition

Версия Python 3.8**

Проблема появилась **после обновления** Ubuntu, сильно мешает работе, **не даёт установить** нужные библиотеки.

Пробовал ввести `sudo apt-get install python3.8-distutils`, выводит:

```
E: Невозможно найти пакет python3.8-distutils           
E: Не удалось найти ни один пакет с помощью шаблона «python3.8-distutils»           
E: Не удалось найти ни один пакет с помощью регулярного выражения «python3.8-distutils»
```

Полная ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/phonik/PycharmProjects/MyСatolog/venv/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/home/phonik/PycharmProjects/MyСatolog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/home/phonik/PycharmProjects/MyСatolog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/home/phonik/PycharmProjects/MyСatolog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.build_env import get_runnable_pip
  File "/home/phonik/PycharmProjects/MyСatolog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/build_env.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.spinners import open_spinner
  File "/home/phonik/PycharmProjects/MyСatolog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/spinners.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
  File "/home/phonik/PycharmProjects/MyСatolog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
  File "/home/phonik/PycharmProjects/MyСatolog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import get_major_minor_version
  File "/home/phonik/PycharmProjects/MyСatolog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
    from . import _distutils
  File "/home/phonik/PycharmProjects/MyСatolog/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/_distutils.py", line 20, in <module>
    from distutils.cmd import Command as DistutilsCommand
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cmd'
```

Comment: нет такого пакета. есть [другой](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=distutils&searchon=names&suite=jammy&section=all)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, его тоже пробовал. Ошибка остаётся

Comment: обновите `pip`: `sudo python3.8 -m pip install pip --upgrade`